# splitting a filename variable to 2 variables in ssis

Tags: ssis, derived

I'm a bit of a newbie to SSIS package creation. I am trying to take a variable `@[User::varFileName]` and split it on an underscore and insert the values into a derived column, eg.

```
@[User::varFileName] = chasehaddon_nov13
```

The derived columns would be

```
list = chasehaddon
datebounced = nov13
```

Currently I'm trying it on using

```
list = SUBSTRING(@[User::varFileName],1,FINDSTRING(@[User::varFileName],"_",1)-1)
datebounced = SUBSTRING(@[User::varFileName],0,FINDSTRING(@[User::varFileName],"_",1)-1)
```

Hope that sort of makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first variable (`list`) looks fine to me, for `datebounced` you should try this:

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::varFileName],FINDSTRING(@[User::varFileName],"_",1) + 1,LEN(@[User::varFileName]) - FINDSTRING(@[User::varFileName],"_",1) + 1)
```

See [`SUBSTRING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms137541.aspx): The second parameter is the position and the third is the length of the wanted substring.

Comment: thanks, this seemed to work, unfortunately the query seems to run incredibly slow now tho. out of interest does this line get executed for every row that i'm importing?

Comment: Two solutions come to my mind: 1. Use a script task to extract the parts to two other variables e.g. `Dts.Variables["User::varList"].Value = Substring(...` or 2. Use property expressions see e.g. [here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/03/19/SSIS_3A00_-Evaluating-variables-as-expressions.aspx) or [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-property-expressions-in-sql-server-integration-services/). If you still have problems with this, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the 2012 version you can do as follows:

```
list=TOKEN([User::varFileName]"_",1)                    
datebounced=TOKEN([User::varFileName]"_",2)
```

Comment: im using 2008 unfortuately